# how install openssl for php 5.3.5 on windows xp?

Tags: php, email, openssl, installation

i want to send emails with gmail in my project and so i should enable openssl(when i checked in phpinfo , that was disabled

---->  OpenSSL support  disabled (install ext/openssl) )...

i am using that latest ver of wamp server :

[DOWNLOAD WampServer 2.1e (32 bits)](http://www.wampserver.com/en/download.php)

Apache 2.2.17

Php 5.3.5

Mysql 5.5.8

PhpMyadmin 3.2.0.1

SQLBuddy 1.3.2

XDebug 2.1.0-5.3

webGrind 1.0

XDC 1.5

---

my os is windows xp //

for install ext/openssl i went to this site

http://www.php.net/manual/en/openssl.installation.php

but i could not install openssl/what exactly should i do for install that ?

would u plz lead me step by step for install ext/openssl?

thanks in future advance

best regards

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming Q&A, not software installation or configuration help. Ask your question on ServerFault or SuperUser.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this problem solved / we should uncomment extension=php_openssl.dll in the php.ini file - 
there are two php.ini files and we should edit that one has a path in phpinfo.

Dan Grossman - Really Thanks - I am so glad for introduce me to ServerFault or SuperUser.

Comment: Note that in some cases you need to run the installer (msi) to add the extension (add dll).