# laravel4 sending email error 'this stream does not support SSL/crypto'

Tags: php, ssl, laravel-4

Now I am using wamp to develop my laravel4 project on windows7. When I sent email to the use I got a error below.

After search the internet the answer is open openssl extendsion.

but I also get this error.

Any ideas? thanks :)

[image]

edit :
extension=php_openssl.dll is UNcommented and phpinfo shows Openssl ennable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering it for windows

Follow these steps

1) Enable extension=php_openssl.dll(Remove ;) in php.ini file.

Note there are going to be 2 .ini files. you need to  edit  the file which found under Apache folder

2) Restart sever

3) Run phpinfo(); and check for openssl, like below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Install php5-openssl (`apt-get install php5-openssl` on Debian and Ubuntu)
2. Restart Apache (`/etc/init.d/apache2 restart` on Debian and Ubuntu)

That should do it.

Comment: Don't forget Step 2!  That's probably the most commonly forgotten step  :)

Comment: but I use windows ): the extendsion has been installed already.

Comment: What does `phpinfo()` say about Openssl?

Comment: Another recommendation - check your php.ini file and make sure `extension=php_openssl.dll` is UNcommented.  From this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850194/how-install-openssl-for-php-5-3-5-on-windows-xp

Comment: yes extension=php_openssl.dll is UNcommented and phpinfo show Openssl ennable  ):